# What determines who you take as a prisoner?

Tags: let-it-die

I've raided a dozen or two lobbies now, but I've only taken a prisoner once. That prisoner got freed, but even afterwards, I never had the option to take another. What determines whether or not I can take a prisoner while raiding and is it random which defending character I can take?

Answer (score 1):

Although many say it's purely random chance, from my experience, it seems you need to perfectly kill them. If you can get a defender's health to exactly 0, it will allow you to capture that defender.

For example, if a defender has 20 health left and you do 30 damage, they die. Otherwise, if they have 20 health left and you do 20 damage, they're just knocked out.

This isn't confirmed, however.